# getting fields from subclass to superclass

Tags: java, inheritance, field, abstract

I'm making a tower defence game and I'm having some issues. I created an abstract class Enemy that has these fields in addition to a couple of methods that use these fields.

```
public abstract class Enemy
{
    public int currentX, currentY;
    //currentX(and Y)PF are used for the pathfinder, they are currentX(and Y) - 1
    public int currentXPF, currentYPF;
    public int health;
    public int velocity;
    public int defense;
    public String orientation;
```

here is one of the functions in the Enemy class.

```
public boolean isDead(){
    if(health == 0){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

what I want to do is define these fields in a subclass (so that I can have one subclass for each type of enemy without them having the same values) but I'm having issues with actually making it work.

```
public class BasicEnemy extends Enemy
{
    public int currentX, currentY;
    public int velocity;
    public int health;
    public int defense;
    public String orientation;

    private static int bounty = 50;


    public BasicEnemy(int currentX,int currentY, Board board) {

        this.health = 3;
        this.defense = 0;
        this.velocity = 1;

        this.currentX = currentX;
        this.currentY = currentY;


        this.currentXPF = currentX - 1;
        this.currentXPF = currentY - 1;

        this.orientation = "right";

        //moveSelf is defined in superclass
        this.moveSelf(board);
    }
```

In another class I have a list of enemies and a function for adding enemies into the list

```
private List<Enemy> enemyList;

public void addEnemy(String type){
switch(type){
//probably not the best solution to use strings for this but whatever
    case "basic":
    enemyList.add(new BasicEnemy(startingX,startingY, this));
    break;
}
}
```

My problem comes up when I try to loop over my enemyList to see if any enemies are dead

```
private void checkForDeadEnemies(){
    List<Enemy> deadEnemies = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Enemy enemy : enemyList){
        if(enemy.isDead()){
            deadEnemies.add(enemy);
        }
    }
    for(Enemy enemy : deadEnemies){
        enemyList.remove(enemy);
        register.increaseBalance(enemy.getBounty());
        notifyAllListeners();
    }
}
```

Currently my problem is that the isDead() function always returns true, even though all of my enemies are BasicEnemy and should have 3 health (since they have no way of taking damage as of yet).

I'm assuming that the isDead() function uses the health field from the Enemy class, which isn't set to anything yet, instead of using the health field from the subclass.

I don't want to use an abstract function since that would lead to lots of repetitive code if I were to make several types of enemies. 
I basically want either my functions in my superclass to use the fields from the subclass, or the fields in the superclass to be set to the values from the subclass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because you're declaring the fields in both the subclass and superclass, so the subclass ends up with 2 copies of those fields, eg `Enemy.currentX` and `BasicEnemy.currentX`. The method in Enemy is checking for the fields declared in `Enemy`, but the `BasicEnemy` subclass is modifying it's own fields. Remove the duplicate declarations in `BasicEnemy`, and it should work fine.

Answer (score 3):

You already have the field `health` defined in `Enemy`, why would you define it in `BasicEnemy` as well? Remove the `health` field from any subclasses of `Enemy` and it will work.